# Laplace transform for two valued function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, laplace-transform, transformation

While I am reading a article, I am stuck with some Lapalce transform.

Let $F(x(t),t)$ be two valued function.

Let's take the Laplace trasnform with resepct to $t$, then the paper says

$$
\int_0^\infty \exp(-\lambda t) F(x(t),t) dt = \widehat{F}(\widehat{x}(\lambda),\lambda)
$$
where $\widehat{x}$ is the Laplace transform of function $x$ and $\widehat{F}(x,\lambda) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-\lambda t)F(x,t)dt$.

I can't understand why this relation is valid.

Comment: That must be a misprint.

Comment: I think so, but I tried some simple exaples and obtained that the above expression is valid. ....

Comment: What is $F$?  If it is a function of two variables, then what is $\hat F$?

Comment: It is defined the Lapalce transform of $F$ for fixed first variable.